# Php header no me está redireccionando

Tags: php

Tengo una cuestión con la redirección de una página phpa  otra. La cuestión es que no redirecciona aunque cuándo yo le doy a enviar la URL cambia, pero la página no se muestra.
La conexión se realiza a una base de datos mysql, el primer código recoge los registros, y el segundo devuelve la información en una tabla

Aquí el código que redirecciona.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        include("conexion.php");

    $cliente = $_POST['name'];
    $observ = $_POST['observaciones'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tb_avisos(name , observaciones) VALUES ('$cliente' , '$observ')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("Unable to do the insertion");

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    header("Location: consultaavisos.php");
    }
?>
```

Y aquí, la página que quiero que se muestre después

```
<?php
       include("conexion.php");

       $query = "SELECT * FROM tbavisos order by fecha_aviso;";

       $result = mysqli_query($conexion , $query);

       

       if(!empty($num_rows) AND mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
       

       

       $devolucion = "Para insertar un nuevo aviso pulse " . "<a href='insertaaviso.php'>Aquí</a></br>";
       
       if($num_rows > 0){
           $devolucion .= 
           "<table>
            <th>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Cliente</td>
                <td>Fecha del aviso</td>
                <td>Fecha de la consulta</td>
                <td>Observaciones</td>
                <td>Estado</td>
            </th>";
      
        while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $registro['id'];
            $cliente = $registro['cliente'];
            $adv_date = $registro['fecha_aviso'];
            $cons_date = $registro['fecha_consulta'];
            $observaciones = $registro['observaciones'];
            $estado = $registro['estado'];

            $devolucion .=
            "<th>
                <td>$id</td>
                <td>$cliente</td>
                <td>$fecha_aviso</td>
                <td>$fecha_consulta</td>
                <td>$observaciones</td>
                <td>$estado</td>
            </th>";
        }
        $devolucion .= "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Has probado con: header("location:/consultaavisos.php")?

Comment: Si que he probado y hace lo mismo, me cambia la url pero el navegador no me carga la página en cuestión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu sentencia PHP estas usando 2 comandos que significan esencialmente lo mismo.

```
if(!empty($num_rows) AND mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
```

cambialo y reemplaza por

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
```

El resto del código estaría bien salvo por un pequeño detalle, no estas haciento un echo de la variable devolucion, que es donde cargas todo el contenido de tu tabla.

Escribe:

```
echo $devolucion;
```

luego de tu variable

```
$devolucion .= "</table>";
```

El otro detalle es que la sentencia :

```
if($num_rows > 0){
```

Es redundante ya que ya se realizó la validación para
ejecutar la sentencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, en el SELECT estaba mal el nombre de la base de datos pero sin todos estos detalles tampoco funcionaría correctamente. Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que dices si que te redirecciona y el problema es en la segunda pagina *consultaavisos.php*

Prueba de poner cualquier cosa en HTML al principio de *consultaavisos.php* o un `echo "hola";` para ver si té carga bien la pagina.

Después ve depurando el codigo por apartados, mira si té funciona la conexion, si entra en el IF y el WHILE

Y como te ha dicho el compañero, imprime la variable $devolucion porque tu codigo no tiene ninguna salida por pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer el redireccionamiento por JS ...
`window.location.href = "enlace"`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        include("conexion.php");

    $cliente = $_POST['name'];
    $observ = $_POST['observaciones'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tb_avisos(name , observaciones) VALUES ('$cliente' , '$observ')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("Unable to do the insertion");

    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href="consultaavisos.php";
    </script>
<?php
    //header("Location: consultaavisos.php");
    }
?>
`
```